# Is the NSA withholding information from Trump?

Tags: donald-trump, nsa

There has been a few ([1](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/nsa-donald-trump-team-ties-russia-mike-flynn-national-security-adviser-daily-intelligence-briefings-a7576986.html), [2](http://www.motherjones.com/kevin-drum/2017/02/nsa-may-be-withholding-intel-president-trump), [3](http://www.haaretz.com/us-news/1.771278)) articles posted lately alleging that the NSA is withholding intelligence from the President. I find this very difficult to believe, and I haven't found any articles with an actual source, other than "a top official".

I just don't see how it would be possible since as soon as the Administration saw the news reports, they would start demanding the intelligence (I would think).

Is there any reason to believe that the NSA is withholding intelligence?

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users)  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: I have not downvoted, just added a comment. I assume that the downvote is due to "There has been a few articles posted" but none of them are in the post.

Comment: What would be considered "evidence" in support of (or against) this claim?

Comment: I think that this is a good question, and there seems to be more behind it than just one unnamed top official. I added some sources for the claim.

Comment: @Oddthinking is there any reason why my comment was removed? Not claiming that you removed it, but most probably one of the moderators. The comment looked reasonable.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: It received a flag. It did nothing to improve the question; it was just speculation about what you thought the priorities of a hypothetical admin would be. Comments are second class citizens. It was deleted without further consideration.

Comment: This needs to be cut down to a specific claim. *Which* information is claimed to be withheld from the president? Without specificity this claim is impossible to disprove.

Comment: The President's intelligence briefings can't possibly include everything. Someone somewhere decides what's important and what is not, what they have confidence in and what they do not, so almost by definition the intelligence agencies are witholdinh information.

Comment: They are just talking about this on CNN. Might be better if we close this as it seems it's ongoing event.